# How to change the database connection dynamically in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012, activebatch

I am learning SSIS day by day and the question might be simple to most of you all but i am stuck on this.
I have to give more background details, We used to have only PROD database earlier and now we started having DEV database with in the same server where my PROD database is.
All my SSIS packages are configured to PROD database. 
I created a variable for connection manager and for the database connection manager i have given expression to pull the variable i defined.

How do i configure when running in my local change the DB connection to DEV and when running of Active Batch server change the connection to PROD db.

Table names, structure are going to be same in DEV and PROD database.

NOTE:I run Active Batch to run my SSIS package and i have env-sys table, when running on Active batch DB connection manager expression will check for environemt_values

Thank you,
S

Comment: how do you run your production packages?

Comment: I think what you are asking is how do I run against DEV in Visual Studio but run against PROD from a job. Is that the case?

Comment: Anyway, i am not going to wait for your answer. Set up a package parameter with a connection string to DEV and configure an express on your OLEDB connection to use that parameter. Then from the job, configure the parameter with PROD connection string.

Comment: I run my production package using Active batch job scheduler. I will set up package parameter and see how it works. I will respond back once i try the option you suggested.